# HTML DOM Parser - How to get the first post of all topics in a forum

Tags: php, screen-scraping, html-parsing, simple-html-dom

I was trying to scrap the first post of every topics in sitepoint javascript forum. But The DOM Parser would give me ALL THE POSTS OF EVERY TOPICS IN SITE POINT JAVASCRIPT FORUM. Maybe I didn't traverse the DOM correctly ? Below is my code:

```
<?php

class Sitepoint extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->helper('dom');
        header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
        echo '<ol>';

            $html = file_get_html('http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/javascript-15');

            foreach($html->find('a[id^="thread_title"]') as $topic) {
                $post =$topic->href;
                $posthtml = file_get_html($post);
                $posthtml->find('div[id^="post_message"]', 0);
                echo'<li>';
                echo $topic->plaintext.'<br>';
                echo $posthtml->plaintext.'<br>';
                echo'</li>';
            }
        echo '</ol>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to assign the result of `$posthtml->find` to a variable:

```
foreach($html->find('a[id^="thread_title"]') as $topic) {
    $post =$topic->href;
    $posthtml = file_get_html($post);
    $posttext = $posthtml->find('div[id^="post_message_"]', 0);
    echo'<li>';
    echo $topic->plaintext.'<br>';
    echo $posttext->plaintext.'<br>';
    echo'</li>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks. With the same code, I can pull 15 topics from other forum at a time, but with sitepoint.com I can only pull 3 first topics. Is that because they use antibot software or my server connection limitation ?

Comment: Well, I tried it now, and after the 30th post I stopped the script. So, this may be an antibot, maybe even your connection is bad :)

Comment: you get 30 posts without looping through pagination ? or with looping through pagination ?